# Dynamic table creation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to create a table that will be dynamically loaded. The table should be appended to the div tag. I need this to be done in jquery. The table values should be given dynamically based on the output of the server.

```
var Obj = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());// My parsed json output
```

I need to display something like

```
 <div id= "er"></div>
<table><tr><td> Value : Obj.ab</td> <td> Value : Obj.cd </td?</tr></table>
```

append the table to div tag and then display the output dynamically using jquery

I need all these to be done using jquery.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: there is a solution. `.append()` is a good way to start

Comment: which is not in the div, use `after()`method

Comment: actually I need the coding to create a table in the above format and to display details.

Comment: JQuery plugin approach can be good solution. You can call $("#er").dataTable({obj : data}) to build a datatable

Answer (score 0):

**Here You Go!**

```
<div id="data">
</div>
```

```js
var div = document.getElementById("data");

var dataObj = {
  name:"XYZ",
  education:"B.Tech",
  country:"ABC"
};
var table       = document.createElement('table');
var thead       = document.createElement('thead');

var thName      = document.createElement('th');
var thCountry   = document.createElement('th');
var thEducation = document.createElement('th');
thName.innerHTML = "Name";
thEducation.innerHTML = "Education";
thCountry.innerHTML = "Country"

thead.appendChild(thName);
thead.appendChild(thEducation)
thead.appendChild(thCountry)

var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

var tdName = document.createElement('td');
var tdEducation = document.createElement('td');
var tdCountry = document.createElement('td');

tdName.innerHTML = dataObj.name;
tdEducation.innerHTML = dataObj.education;
tdCountry.innerHTML = dataObj.country;

tr.appendChild(tdName);
tr.appendChild(tdEducation);
tr.appendChild(tdCountry);
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tr);
div.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: I want my table to be appended with a div tag and to load it dynamically.

Comment: dude I need jquery not javascript.